# How having count() display 0 when no result?

Tags: mysql, count, coalesce

Although the title suggest that it was already answered, I tried all the suggestion and just couldn't make it in my case:

I have one table with 2 columns, Week holding the week number, and Worktype holding the type of activities during these weeks. There are 2 discticnt type of activities (debug, integration) and there can be several entries for each week.
Typically:

```
+------+-------------+
| week | worktype    |
+------+-------------+
|   12 | debug       |
|   12 | debug       |
|   12 | debug       |
|   12 | integration |
|   12 | debug       |
|   12 | debug       |
|   12 | debug       |
|   12 | debug       |
|   12 | debug       |
|   12 | debug       |
|   12 | integration |
|   12 | debug       |
|   12 | debug       |
+------+-------------+
```

I would like to display, for each week, the numer of occurences of "integration".
I tried

`Select`week`, count(`worktype`) from xxx where`worktype`="integration"`

And it works fine for some weeks, but just doesn't display anything for others (the weeks where there was no integration are not displayed).

I tried using `coalesce(count(`worktype`),0)` but it doesn't help in this case, as the result is never NULL, so coalesce never replaces it by zero.
Tried `find_in_set()` which does not help neither ...

Any suggestion ?

Thanks,
Jacques

Answer (score 1):

You can do a SUM on a field calculated in an IF:-

```
SELECT week, SUM(IF(worktype="debug", 1, 0)) AS Debug_Count, SUM(IF(worktype="integration", 1, 0)) AS Integration_Count
FROM xxx
GROUP BY week
```

Or to just get a single column for the worktype you care about, and avoid the IFs:-

```
SELECT Sub1.week, COUNT(xxx.worktype)
FROM (SELECT DISTINCT week 
FROM xxx) Sub1
LEFT OUTER JOIN xxx
ON Sub1.week = xxx.week
AND xxx.worktype = "integration"
GROUP BY week
```

Comment: Terrific ! it works as expected, with the IF's. Thanks. I cano easily add a column for compatibility reason with an existing system I am trying to replace :-(